# Explode Foreach

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

Total newbie to PHP, but my employer has me working on a project that requires knowledge of it. I have a text file (date.txt) with ";" as a delimiter. This is a sample of what's in the text file:

```html
March 4, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 11, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 18, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 25, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
```

We'll have a user select a date from a button -- let's say they choose March 11, 2020. I then need them to be able to see the options "associated" with March 11, 2020 (i.e. 7:30 AM, 8:00 AM, etc.).

I know I can accomplish this with a foreach/if statement, but I'm stuck! Here's the code I have so far:

```html
<?PHP
$file_handle = fopen("resources/date.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

$path = fgets($file_handle);
$explode = explode(";", $path); //make array from values
foreach ($explode as $segment) {
    if (!in_array($values['March 4, 2020'], $array)) { //check whether catid is in array
        print $parts[1] . $parts[2] . $parts[3] . $parts[4] . $parts[5] . $parts[6] ."<BR>"; // execute whatever you want
    }
}
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

If I execute it as is, I end up with the output of a ton of "December 30, 2020".

EDIT:
This is what I've got up to now:

```html
<?php
 $dateSelected = "March 4, 2020";

if ($fd = fopen("resources/date.txt", "r")) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fd, 10000, ";")) !== false) {
  $parts = explode(';', $line_of_text);
        if ($data[0] == $dateSelected) {
            $option1 = $parts[1]. "<BR>";
   $option2 = $parts[2]. "<BR>";
   $option3 = $parts[3]. "<BR>";
   $option4 = $parts[4]. "<BR>";
   $option5 = $parts[5]. "<BR>";
   $option6 = $parts[6]. "<BR>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option1; ?> </a> <?php
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option2; ?> </a> <?php
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option3; ?> </a> <?php
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option4; ?> </a> <?php
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option5; ?> </a> <?php
?>
<a class="btn-lg"> <?php
echo $option6; ?> </a> <?php


/* Gives you 7:30 AM, 8:00 AM, 8:30 AM, 9:00 AM, 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM */
  
  
  ?>
```

When run, it returns the row of buttons I'm looking for, the values it returns are for the absolute last date in the file, not the actual date selected.

Comment: `$values`, `$array` and `$parts` aren't set anywhere. And `$segment` isn't used anywhere either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method to do this is to use regex.
The benefit is if the file is large then there is no looping and it can be quicker.

```
$str = "March 4, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 11, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 18, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 25, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM";

$date = "March 4, 2020";

preg_match("/". preg_quote($date) . "; (.*)/", $str, $times);

echo $times[1];
```

Outputs:

```
7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
```

The code finds the date and then captures the rest of the line.
It returns the string of times `'; '` delimited but can easily be changed to anything with a str_replace or an explode if it's an array you want.

https://3v4l.org/80qjf

Comment: I went with this approach. It accomplished exactly what I needed it to do with the least code necessary. I ended up using explode(';', $times); to get each delimited value separately.

Comment: @Bulldawg13 good that you liked my code. Do you mind accepting the answer so that everyone sees this is the method you liked?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is essentially parsing a CSV file and looking to match the first cell in a given row to your selected date then return the proceeding cells from that row.

This can be done similar to the following:

```
$csvData = <<<'CSVDATA'
March 4, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 11, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 18, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 25, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
CSVDATA;

$data = [];

foreach (explode("\n", $csvData) as $line) {
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line, ";");
}

$dateSelected = "March 4, 2020";

foreach ($data as $row) {
    if ($row[0] == $dateSelected) {
        $options = array_slice($row, 1);
        break;
    }
}

echo implode(",", $options);
/* Gives you 7:30 AM, 8:00 AM, 8:30 AM, 9:00 AM, 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM */
```

In your case, you'd be reading from a file instead of a string so you'd be using [`fget_csv()`](http://php.net/fget-csv) instead.

In other words you'd be doing something more like this...

```
$dateSelected = "March 4, 2020";

if ($fd = fopen("resources/date.txt", "rb")) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fd, 10000, ";")) !== false) {
        if ($data[0] == $dateSelected) {
            $options = array_slice($data, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo implode(",", $options);
/* Gives you 7:30 AM, 8:00 AM, 8:30 AM, 9:00 AM, 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM */
```

Comment: What's the possibility of getting each cell to the right of the selected date into its own value? My goal is to create a "subset" of buttons, with a button for each value to the right of the selected data.

i.e. - They select March 4, 2020, and 6 other buttons pop up (one button each for 7:30 AM, 8:30 AM, etc.)

Comment: That does get each cell. `var_dump($options)`

Answer (score 0):

@Sherif beat me to it, but I was running through a similar solution. I've changed it a bit to rebuild each line as an associative array, keyed by date, with an array of times in it:

```
// Building $file as string for example purposes
$file = "March 4, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 11, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 18, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM
March 25, 2020; 7:30 AM; 8:00 AM; 8:30 AM; 9:00 AM; 9:30 AM; 10:00 AM";

$array = explode( PHP_EOL, $file ); // Blow this up at end of line, not ;
$final = array();

foreach( $array as $value ){
    // Get the parts of the string
    $parts = explode( ';', $value );

    // Set the Key
    $key = $parts[0];

    // Unset the key from the remainder
    unset( $parts[0] );

    // Cleanup whitespace
    $parts = array_map( 'trim', $parts );

    // Add the new key => value pairs to final array
    $final[$key] = $parts;
}

/*
    //$final output:
    array(4) {
        ["March 4, 2020"]=> array(6) {
            [1]=> string(7) "7:30 AM"
                …
            [6]=> string(8) "10:00 AM"
        }
        ["March 11, 2020"]=> array(6) {
            [1]=> string(7) "7:30 AM"
                …
            [6]=> string(8) "10:00 AM"
        }
            …
    }
*/

/*
    // $final['March 11, 2020'] output:
    array(6) {
    [1]=> string(7) "7:30 AM"
        …
    [6]=> string(8) "10:00 AM"
    }
*/
```

Comment: No need to trim the parts if you use the correct delimiter in the explode

Comment: I considered using `; ` (space after) as the delimiter, but given the format (a seemingly arbitrary .txt file) I assumed it would be safer to explode it at the `;` regardless and run it through `trim` just in case. Don't need the accidental `7:30 AM;8:00 AM` not being exploded. Also considered `preg_split()` but thought that was a bit heavy-handed for something like this.